# error installing a package " Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content. "

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i am trying to install spatie/sitemap package on my laravel package but i keep getting this error i don't know what's the problem :

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```sh
    - spatie/crawler[5.0.2, ..., v5.x-dev] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.4 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.4.0, ..., 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.0.0 
(lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - spatie/crawler[5.0.0, ..., 5.0.1] require php ^7.4 -> your php version (8.0.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - spatie/crawler 7.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.8 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.0.0 (lock 
file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - spatie/laravel-sitemap 6.0.4 requires spatie/crawler ^5.0 || ^7.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/crawler[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, v5.x-dev, 7.0.0].
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-sitemap 6.0.4 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-sitemap[6.0.4].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

i tried to specify the version of the package and used the latest one 6.0.4 but it didn't work too and i have no idea what to do !! please some help .

**UPDATE**

this is composer.json :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "alexpechkarev/google-maps": "^8.0",
    "appstract/laravel-opcache": "^4.0",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.6",
    "mews/captcha": "^3.2",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.48",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Your PHP version doesn't satisfy one of the requirements, and then the package that you are trying to use is locked to the version set of the project file.

Comment: @MysticSeagull i am using the latest version of PHP and LARAVEL .. is there a way to fix that !

Comment: Yes, and its telling you the requirement isn't met for what it's looking for. nothing wrong with the version side of that of using the latest or not, the list of versions are what the packages need to be for the requirement of spatie/sitemap to be met to install

Comment: @MysticSeagull so what should i do !

Comment: exactly as it says, modify the composer.json and update to the versions that satisfy the requirements, then re-run the installation of the package

Comment: How did you require that package? Through using `composer require`, or through manually editing the `composer.json`?

Comment: @NicoHaase through composer require, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work by installing and enabling php exif, first i installed a php exif package through composer and then i enabled it from php.ini and it worked perfectly .

Comment: Can you share more details? Which part of the error message makes you think that exif is in any way related here?

Comment: @NicoHaase i had an error message saying i need to enable the extension and php exif was the only extension written in the error message so i just tried it and it worked, this error msg i am talking about appeared after i added -W

Answer (score 1):

`spatie/sitemap`  requires `spatie/crawler`, and this one (even in the latest version) requires v1 of `guzzlehttp/psr7`. That's no surprise, as v2 of that package is just three weeks old, and `spatie/crawler` hasn't been updated since then.

To get to a solution, just read the error message:

> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Composer might help you to resolve the dependency problem, but only if you tell it to do so by using the `-W` flag.

---

If this does not work: you might need to check which other package requires `guzzlehttp/psr7` in v2. That is a pretty recent version, and `composer why-not guzzlehttp/psr7 1.8.2` might list any package that forbids downgrading this package. If this does list any conflicting packages, you need to check further which one needs a downgrade

Comment: @Nico.Haase it didn't work when i added (-W) and i tried composer why-not guzzlehttp/psr7 1.8.2 and i got this : " There is no installed package depending on "guzzlehttp/psr7" in versions not matching 1.8.2 "

Comment: Then please edit your question to contain more details, like the current state of `composer.json`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem installing Google's apiclient and I solved it by adding the following option:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.10 --with-all-dependencies
```